# cannot convert Type TensorType(float32, matrix) (of Variable Subtensor{::,int64:int64:}.0) into Type TensorType(float32, 3D)

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano

I have looked up the problem on the internet and haven't been able to find the solution for. It is said that the y and dataset_y don't match, but when I print the y.type and train_y.type, both of them are: TensorType(int32,vector). The code I've written is as follow:

```
import theano.function
import theano.tensor as T

y=T.ivector('y')
train=theano.function([i],classifier.errors(y),
    givens={
         x:train_x[i*batch:(i+1)*batch]
         y:train_y[i*batch:(i+1)*batch]}allow_input_downcast=True)
```

Comment: The problem may be with `x`, not `y`. Check `x.type` and `train_x.type`

Comment: BTW @hunter, I saw that you closed an earlier question when you discovered the answer yourself. StackOverflow encourages people to answer their own questions in such circumstances to aid people in the future that have the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for remind, i opened it again and answered it. @DanielRenshaw